# Display alert with an image?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I know how to display a custom alert with phonegap. I want to add an image to it. Can I do that?

My goal is a loading dialog, with some text and a progressbar.gif.

Comment: Why am i being downvoted here? A comment would be nice.

Comment: http://WhatHaveYouTried.com, You're probably getting downvoted because we're all volunteering our time to answer these questions, and expect you to try to find a solution before posting here.

Comment: Thanks for replying it. I couldn't post anything that I tried because I had no idea where to start from. There are no references about this in the documentation. It's fairly easy to do it in android but  I'm a begginer in javascript so I did my best and I still couldn't get anything close to what I need. I don't think this is a question that should be closed, it's an issue in Phonegap and a lot of people could use it. Maybe I wrote it the wrong way and you can suggest me a better way to write it but I don't believe this deserve to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a hidden div in the middle of the screen with the loading dialog and the progressbar.gif, then you only have to show or hide it with javascript.

If you want a native alert, it's not possible

Comment: I wanted the native alert, but if it's not possible I suppose that will do the trick.Thanks!

Comment: For native alert you'll need a plugin because with the regular alert for iOS you can't use images. You can "hack" the alert to show an image, but the gif wont be animated, there are some ways to animate a gif, but it's not easy. So the short answer is no, the long answer is you can with a plugin an a lot of work, and this is just for iOS, I supose it won't be easy on android neither.

Comment: In android it's easy to customize your alert but I have to avoid using plugins as much as I can so the hidden div will do the trick! Thanks :)